# Django architect table partitioning

Tags: mysql, django, partitioning

I need to partition a table. I'm trying to use architect. Please find the model class below.

```
@architect.install('partition', type='range', subtype='integer', constraint='10000', column='user_id')
class PracticeAttempt(models.Model):
    id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id         = models.IntegerField()
    question_id     = models.IntegerField()
    time_taken      = models.IntegerField(default=0)    
    num_attempts    = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    start_time      = models.DateTimeField()        
    bookmark        = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        app_label = settings.APP_SUBMISSION
        db_table = 'practice_attempts'
        unique_together = ('user_id', 'question_id')
```

At the time of data insertion, I'm getting this error

> PartitionRangeSubtypeError: Unsupported partition range subtype "date" in "PracticeSubmission" model, supported range subtypes for "mysql" database are: date.

I even tried `subtype = "date", constraint = "year" & column = "start_time"`, still I'm getting the same error. Please help me.

Comment: Please explain what you hope to gain by partitioning by range.

Comment: I'm expecting 10K+ entries per user and #user will be in million. So I want to partition the table to have a limit on number of entries.

Comment: That won't "limit" the number of entries in any way; it will just spread them among the partitions.  I am asking because people often get into partitioning without understanding what partitions will and _will not_ do for them.

Comment: But that's what the documentation says "Table partitioning is a division of one table into several tables". Please update me, how can I fulfill my requirement.

Comment: Since there is no "limit on number of entries" on either a table or a partition, I don't understand what the "requirement" is.  I do not accept "need to partition a table" as a "requirement", only as "a means to an end".

Comment: two years later, I get a similar error:
`architect partition: error: unsupported partition range subtype "varchar" in "Parcel" model, supported range subtypes for "postgresql" database are:`

I don't know why the OP should have to explain why they need partitions, in order to get an answer

Answer (score 0):

The rrror states that the problem is with `PracticeSubmission`, not `PracticeAttempt`. If `PracticeSubmission` inherits from `PracticeAttempt` you need to decorate it so architect can ignore it:

```
@architect.install('partition', type='range', subtype='integer', constraint='10000', column='user_id')
class PracticeAttempt(models.Model):
    id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id         = models.IntegerField()
    question_id     = models.IntegerField()
    time_taken      = models.IntegerField(default=0)    
    num_attempts    = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    start_time      = models.DateTimeField()        
    bookmark        = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        app_label = settings.APP_SUBMISSION
        db_table = 'practice_attempts'
        unique_together = ('user_id', 'question_id')



@architect.uninstall('partition')
class PracticeSubmission:
    ...
```